# Assign and compare against uint(-1)

Tags: c++

In StarCitizen Bugsmashers [about tick rates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpOOUsb316I) a code snippet like this is visible:

```
uint i = someBool ? someuint : uint(-1);
// ... some other code ...
if (i == uint(-1)) { /* do something */ }
```

In case `someBool` is false, then `i = 4294967295` which is `0xFFFFFFFF`/the maximum 32bit uint value:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const auto i = uint(-1);
    if (i == uint(-1))
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

I assume, the motivation for doing this is to avoid having to use another control variable for the if statement. Is the construction of `uint(-1)` defined behaviour? If yes, why?

Comment: Do you mean `uint(-1)` or `(uint)-1`?

Comment: The construction `uint(-1)`, not the cast.

Comment: Why that instead of something like `-1UL`? This is really *odd* code.